# Difference between "tcp/socket" vs "tcp/ip"

Tags: sockets, tcp

What is the difference between a "tcp/socket" and "tcp/ip" connexion?

When you say that you use "tcp/ip", do you necessarily use a "tcp/socket"?

Thanks!

Comment: The question is missing context for me. In general TCP/IP is a protocol, Sockets are a programming API. When implementing networked programs TCP/IP is typically used with this Sockets API.

Comment: The context is that I want to document a data flow between two applications residing on two different servers.

What I'm told is that the way they communicate is via "tcp / socket". Does saying that necessarily imply that it uses "tcp / ip"?

Comment: This just means that the communication is done with TCP/IP and the programming API you use to implement this communication is the socket interface.

Answer (score 0):

A socket is a general communication means provided by your
operating system.
There are many kinds of them, for very distinct purposes
(not only networking).
I guess that when you think about tcp/socket, you mean a
socket dedicated to the TCP protocol.

TCP/IP can be seen as two different things, depending on the context.
It can be the TCP/IP network stack as a whole: not only the TCP and IP
specific protocols but the set of protocols (and implementations) we
find around these.
Of course, the other way to see TCP/IP is to consider only the TCP
transport protocol relying on the IP network protocol.

The various operating systems implement many protocols
in the TCP/IP stack.
To use them, a programmer asks his/her operating system
a specific resource: a socket.

It's difficult to say more with few words.
Some books or online documentation could help go further.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing something in the question. Anyway in short...

TCP/IP is basically name given to protocol we (networking devices) follow it forms the fundamental of todays internet. It involves agreement between two devices how the want ro communicate eg. Which segment of a frame has what information as in the end its all just 10...
There are 5 layers (some argue 4) in this model one layer is Network Layer right at the middle of all and it generally uses IPv4.And  just above this is our Transport Layer which may use TCP or UDP as protocol depending on service you want. So thats the summary of TCP/ IP as the most used set of protocols of all.

When connecting to a remote server your browser needs to know what kind of service he is about to get from that server eg.  a video mail or file transfer or just a http page. Thats when a TCP/Socket comes into picture where there is a port no assigned for every service. Eg port 443 is for https and so on. All you need to do is open a socket connection over that port number on that machine

Remember if a particular port of a server is not in LISTEN mode you cannot connect to that application via that port
Eg. If a server serves its webpage it might not allow you to connect its port responsible for FTP.